# Detecting when a fragment has focus again

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have two fragments, when a button in the first fragment is clicked, I load a the second fragment and add the previous fragment to the backstack.

```
getActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment2)
       .addToBackStack(null)
       .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE)
       .commit()
```

The result is that pressing back closes the second fragment and returns me to the previous fragment, which is exactly how I want it. HOWEVER there are certain elements on the first fragment that should be refreshed at this point. When the user clicks back and is returned to the first fragment, how do I know to refresh the data within that fragment? is there a method such as onResume() for this scenario?

Comment: You have more than one solution
1- LiveData
2- u can define in BaseFragment global variable and change value in the second fragment when u back to first fragment in onResume () update your value.

Comment: Thanks! onResume is not invoked in this scenario, it is only invoked when the 1st fragment is starting, it is not invoked when i am back from the 2nd fragment to the 1st fragment. LiveData sounds good, I will try to implement it in all my fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you call this inside the first fragment, you should call `hide` try this

```
getActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .add(R.id.frame_layout, fragments)
       .hide(this)
       .addToBackStack(null)
       .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE)
       .commit()
```

Inside first fragment override `onHiddenChanged` callback

```
    @Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        if (!hidden) {
            // refresh your data here
        }
    }
```